# Lost focus when viewModel is updated

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus

I would like to update row of datagrid when selection is changed.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Strint rowID = ((String)((DataGrid)sender).SelectedValue);

    RadekTabulky row = Client.getRadek(rowID);
    if(row != null)
    {
        dataGrid.SelectionChanged -= DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
        int index = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
        viewModel.Sumy = new SumStorage(viewModel.Soubor, viewModel.Radky);
        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = index;
        dataGrid.SelectionChanged += DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

I wrote this simple code. But when I click on row, the row is selected, updated but it looks like grid lost focus and I cannot see which row is selected. When I click again at same row, it will get that blue color indicating it is selected.

Is there a way how to update viewModel without losing this focus?

Comment: Don't manipulate `dataGrid.SelectedIndex = index;`. By the way, why are you doing this? The index doesn't change or is used, so this line is redundant. Also you don't need to remove the event handler just to register it at the end of the method. Invocation of `DataGrid_SelectionChanged` is synchronous so the handler can only get called once.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for advice. I already tried to remove all lines except `viewModel.Sumy = ...`, but in this case, focus is also lost and row is not selected (at least by visual side)